# Comment nomme-t-on les différents stades de l'enfance ?

Tags: vocabulaire, société, enfants

Sur un autre site SE a pour le moment lieu un mini-débat. Je me réfère à [cette question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3495/at-what-age-does-a-toddler-stop-being-a-toddler) en anglais. Son titre :

> At what age does a toddler stop being a toddler?

Le débat porte sur le site dans lequel cette question devrait être posée. Elle a été migrée de "English language" vers "Parenting" par Jeff Atwood lui-même, argumentant que lui et sa femme avaient, en tant que parents, déjà discuté autour de la même question.

Je ne suis pas d'accord avec lui car le seul fait que je ne puisse pas avoir ce débat en français avec ma femme - ne trouvant pas de traduction à "toddler" - me laisse penser qu'il s'agit bien d'une question de langage.

Et vous, auriez-vous une traduction ayant un sens similaire à "toddler" ? D'une manière plus générale, quels mots utilisez-vous pour décrire les différents stades de l'enfance ?

Comment: il y a "rug rat" aussi en anglais, que reverso. traduit. comme "poupon".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il n'existe pas vraiment de traduction exacte de *toddler*.

Le mot français **bébé** englobe à la fois *baby* et *toddler*. Des périphrases comme « c'est encore un bébé », « il va à la crêche », « il marche à quatre pattes » ou « il apprend à marcher » peuvent convenir.

On cesse d'être un bébé quand on rentre à l'école maternelle, l'année de ses 3 ans (en France).

Quant aux différents stades de l'enfance associés ici à des lieux, en voici une liste :

- nouveau-né (maternité)
- nourisson (maison/crêche)
- bébé (englobe les deux précédents) (crêche, les tout-petits)
- enfants, gosses, bambins, gamins (peuvent englober tous les autres termes) (maternelle: les petits / primaire: les grands)
- pré-adolescents (collège)
- adolescents (collège)
- jeunes (lycée)

Comment: http://www.reverso.net/text_translation.aspx?lang=FR donne *bambin* ; http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/toddler donne *bambin*, *tout-petit*

Comment: @cl-r le spectre de bambin, comme ceux de gosse et gamin, est similaire à celui d'enfant (*child/kid*). Il est beaucoup plus large que celui de *toddler* qui désigne une période bien définie. Remarque: éviter «gosse» au Québec ;-)

Comment: Le spectre de "enfant" est même encore plus large. Du haut de mes 36 ans je reste l'enfant de mes parents; même s'ils parlent sans doute plus souvent de moi comme leur "fils" que comme leur "enfant", si j'avais une soeur nous serions leurs "enfants", sans que je puisse penser à un autre mot usuel pour décrire la relation.

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui c'est vrai. On peut cependant distinguer « l'enfant de, les enfants de » qui dénotent la filiation sans notion d'age, la « progéniture » et « un enfant, des enfants », termes généraux qui excluent normalement les adultes.

Answer (score 2):

Dans la vie courante, *toddler* correspond aux *petits-enfants* qui ont l'âge d'aller à l'école maternelle, on les appelle aussi *bambin, tout-petit* et plus familièrement *schtroumpf, ti-nain* (contraction de petit. nain).

Plus récent et proche de l'anglais, le *trottineur* (Cf. le commentaire de Divulgâchâmes) semble accepté depuis le *IIIe* millénaire, mais n'est pas ancore arrivé dans les correcteurs orthographiques ; il semble plus utilisé au Québec qu'en France.

---

On peut traduire la question par:

> À quel âge un bambin s'arrête-t-il d'être un bambin ? (mot à mot)
>
> À quel âge un bambin n'est plus un bambin ?
>
> On n'est plus un bambin à partir de quel âge ?

La définition de *[bambin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/bambin)* (appelé aussi *tout-petit* dans les écoles maternelles) :

> *Fam. et affectueux*. Jeune enfant, dont l'âge se situe le plus souvent entre **2 et 10 ans**.

on peut extraire non exhaustivement parmi ceux qui on une maturité variable :

> ...un bambin de **deux ans et demi**,...
>
> ... était un homme de dix-huit ans tandis que j'étais encore un bambin de **treize ou quatorze**.
>
> ... et la majesté avec laquelle un bambin **de vingt ans** déjeune chez Tortoni.

Il existe aussi *[chérubin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/ch%C3%A9rubin)*,  mais pour assimiler un *bambin* à un ange il faut une bonne dose d'amour, d'aveuglement parental ou trouver une similarité avec les images qu'en donnent les grands peintres du Ciel.

Vos discussions familiales sont loin d'être closes, selon que l'on parle de l'enfant, de l'âge mental, du comportement ou que l'on change de point de vue : parent, écrivain, humoriste ...

- Au début c'est assez clair : *nouveau-né, bébé, bambin* (ou *tout-petit*, avant *l'âge de raison* que certains fixe à sept ans [comprendre six ans révolus ?] et d'autres à partir de six ans, selon l'évolution de l'enfant), *enfant,* ou *gamin* familièrement,
- zone incertaine :  *pré-ado, adolescent,*
- ensuite *majeur, jeune homme/jeune femme (jeunes gens)*,
- pour finir *adulte* (qui peut commencer très tôt parfois avant la majorité, ou très tard pour les *[Tanguy](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=29078.htm)*) qui sera suivi des périodes de vieillesse : *senior, troisième et quatrième âge*.

Cette échelle peut être comprise par tous ou remise en cause selon sa propre histoire.

Cela ne donne pas un âge numérique, mais un moment de l'évolution personnelle qui varie de façon singulière pour chacun.

Comment: Merci. J'avais effectivement pensé à bambin, mais comme tu le mentionnes cela a un sens assez large. en anglais cela semble être tout aussi discutable avec cependant une moins grande flexibilité car il semble qu'au delà de 4 ou 5 ans le terme "toddler" devienne déjà incongru.

Comment: @LaurentS. Normalement bambin est pour les 2/6 ans, avant l'âge de raison. J'ai modifié l'échelle. Les exemples du CNRTL sont littéraires, l'usage familiale de *bambin* est avant l'enfance, avant l'âge de raison. Ensuite on passe à *gamin* (enfant familièrement)

Comment: @LaurentS. J'ai ajouté *chérubin*, mais vous risquez quelques sourires si vous désignez sérieusement vos enfants ainsi devant des personnes qui n'auront pas forcément le même point de vue sur votre progéniture.

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes - Merci de vos précisions qui sont maintenant intégrées dans la réponse.